# How do I share variables inside a singleton class

Tags: swift, parsing, singleton

I am trying to create a common class for storing and retrieving data in Parse. I made the ParseProcessing class a singleton class. From my main View Controller I load the data and store it into a dictionary in the ParseProcessing. I do this by creating a shared instance of the ParseProcessing class. From another view controller I try to access the data from the dictionary. I assumed that because ParseProcessing is a singleton class that I have a single copy of the dictionary. This does not appear to be correct. How should I declare the variables inside the ParseProcessing so that they are shared? The code is shown below:

```
import UIKit

var gSep = ","

class QwikFileViewController: UIViewController {

var loadData = ParseProcessing.sharedInstance

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // load data from Parse
    loadData.loadCategorySubcategoryData()
    loadData.loadRecordsFromParse()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

ParseProcessing Singleton Class

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ParseProcessing: Parse  {


var dictMenuList = [String:String]()
var noteTitle = [String]()
var notes = [String]()
var thumbnailFiles = [PFFile]()
var objectIds = [String]()
var noteImage = UIImage()


class var sharedInstance:ParseProcessing {

    struct singleton {

        static let instance:ParseProcessing = ParseProcessing()
    }

    return singleton.instance
}
// Load Category/Subcategory data from Parse Data Base

func loadRecordsFromParse () -> Bool{
    var tmpFile = [PFFile]()
    var loadComplete = false
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Record")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) items.")
            for object in objects! {
                self.noteTitle.append(object["title"] as! String)
                self.notes.append(object["notes"] as! String)
                self.thumbnailFiles.append(object["thumbnail"] as! PFFile)
                       self.objectIds.append(String(stringInterpolationSegment: object.objectId))
            }
        } else {
            println("\(error)")
       }
        loadComplete = true
    }


    return loadComplete
}

// Load Category/Subcategory data from Parse Data Base

func loadCategorySubcategoryData () // -> Dictionary <String,String> 
    {
    var success : Bool = false
    var d : Dictionary <String,String> = ["":""]
    var menu = PFQuery(className: "Classification")
    println("ParseProcessing: loadCategory...")
    menu.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            var category = ""
            var subcategory = ""
            for object in objects! {

                category = object["category"] as! String
                println("ParseProcessing: category = \(category)")

                subcategory = object["subcategory"] as! String
                println("ParseProcessing: subcategory = \(subcategory)")
                d[category] = subcategory
            }
            success = true
            self.dictMenuList = d
            return
        } else {
            println("ParseProcessing: error = \(error)")
            success = false
        }

    }
   return
}

}
```

Another View Controller to examine the data

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

var dictMenuList = [String:String]()
var loadData  = ParseProcessing.sharedInstance

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dictMenuList = loadData.dictMenuList
    println("dictMenuList: \(dictMenuList)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, Swift 1.2 now permits `static` class properties, so you can eliminate all of that `sharedInstance` code and replace it with one line, `shared let sharedInstance = ParseProcessing()`.

Comment: Also unrelated, but I'd advise against having all of those separate arrays for `noteTitle`, `notes`, `thumbnail`, etc. What if you wanted to sort this by title: You'd have to manually sort all of those separate arrays. You should instead define a custom class that has properties for each of those. Then have a single array of custom objects rather than separate arrays for each of the properties.

Comment: Rob: Thank you for both these suggestions. I will change the arrays to be one array of a struct. Hopefully that is a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is asynchronous method (i.e. it returns immediately but the closure is called later when the query is done). So you cannot return `loadComplete` in `loadRecordsFromParse`, for example. This background request will almost certainly never be done by the time `loadRecordsFromParse` returns.

Instead, you probably want to adopt the `completionHandler` pattern. For example, this sample `loadRecords` doesn't try to return anything immediately, but rather will call the `completionHandler` when the request is done.

```
func loadRecords(completionHandler:([SomeObject]?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "SomeClass")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
        // build some model object
        completionHandler(objectArray, error)
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
loadData.loadRecords() { objects, error in
    // use `objects` (and make sure `error` is `nil`) here
}

// but do not use those variables here, as the above closure probably has not run yet!
```

Frankly, I'd be inclined to get rid of those properties in your singleton altogether. When you're dealing with asynchronous code, to have public properties that are updated asynchronously is going to be a source of heartache. You *can* do it, but it wouldn't be my first choice.

For example, when `TestViewController` is presented, you cannot assume that the  asynchronous fetch associated with `dictMenuList` is done yet. I look at this and wonder if it makes sense for `TestViewController` to initiate the fetch itself and then use `dictMenuList` in the completion handler. That's going to be easiest.

If you must initiate the asynchronous request from one view controller and then have another view controller be informed when that asynchronous request is done, then you might have to use some other pattern, such as notifications (e.g. use `NSNotificationCenter`, and have the singleton post notifications when the various requests are done, and then any view controller that needs to be informed of this fact can add themselves as observers for that notification).

Comment: Rob: Thank you, again. Let me try out your suggestions. I have struggled with the asynchronous updates and I am stumped. The notification pattern probably is the most promising so I will try that out next. I posted this question hoping that others have solved this issue since Parse is commonly used.

Comment: Good luck. The `completionHandler` pattern is going to be easiest and is the customary solution. I'd only go down the notification pattern if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestions. Specifically, regarding your suggestion on calling TestViewController initiating the fetch, would it not be equivalent to making the fetch synchronous? In my actual implementation, the TestViewController has a UIPicker which needs to be populated. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352651/how-to-synchronize-a-parse-read-image-with-screen-display-in-ios. I may have to go back to a redesign of my whole app to deal with this issue. Specifically, when the request for the UIPicker is made, I may have to initiate an activity indicator. Not very cool.

Comment: It may feel functionally equivalent to synchronous call, but technically it's much better and avoids all sorts of problems. Having said that, if you achieve a superior UX by initiating the asynchronous request earlier and post notification when its done, that's fine, but it's just a little more complicated. I misread your comment as suggesting that you might have been new to async programming, so I wanted to steer you to the simpler solution, but if you're confident in your async patterns, then go wild.

Comment: Actually, I am less confident about async as you guessed and I need to read a text book. Your suggestions were very valuable to steer me.

Comment: Rob: Implemented NSNotification as suggested and it works fine. Additional benefit is that I have an easy way of sending the data without worrying about the issue of sharing data. The userInfo allows me to send a dictionary variable. Thanks for your help.